# Regex - documentation

Tags: c#, regex

Hello all I am going through some old code and ran across a reg-ex, I cant figure out what it does, Can anyone shed some light on it.

```
<(.|\n)*?>|{(.|\n)*?}
```

it was in a replace string.replace statement.

Comment: You should definitely click on that [link](http://bit.ly/1fV9eHg)

Comment: @MaxS - Real funny! I love when someone has such a superiority complex that they must take every opportunity they can to just show it off, if you did not feel like answering the question, or even thought it was stupid question you should simply just ignore it.

Comment: sorry to have offended you. The aim was not to show off or something. Even if it was some sort of (bad, I admit) joke, the provided link does lead you to a pretty nice tool to help you out with regex. My comment was a way to say what it's written on the Search and Research section of that [SO help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But once again, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your regex into [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/)

At the bottom is a guide titled `Your regular expression explained`

Answer (score 0):

According to RegexBuddy this is what it dose:

```
Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «<(.|\n)*?>»
   Match the character “<” literally «<»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.|\n)*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
      Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*?»
      Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «.»
         Match any single character that is not a line break character «.»
      Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «\n»
         Match a line feed character «\n»
   Match the character “>” literally «>»
Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «{(.|\n)*?}»
   Match the character “{” literally «{»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.|\n)*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
      Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*?»
      Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «.»
         Match any single character that is not a line break character «.»
      Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «\n»
         Match a line feed character «\n»
   Match the character “}” literally «}»
```

The Matches are:

```
<>
<...>
{}
{...}
```

when ... is any text